# Split a dataframe about a column of a character in a special manner

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to pandas, want some guidance from you smart folks.

`df.head()`:

```
feature_category
transgender_gender
725-750_crif_score
<25_age
<575_crif_score
```

I want to make a separate column containing the string after the first under score.

`df`:

```
feature_category.             feature_name
transgender_gender              gender 
725-750_crif_score              crif_score
<25_age                         age
<575_crif_score                 crif_score
```

Please guide to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.split` method and setting parameter `n=1`, which limits the number of splits to 1. Then use the `str` accessor to select the second part:

```
df['feature_name'] = df['feature_category'].str.split('_', 1).str[1]
```

Output:

```
     feature_category feature_name
0  transgender_gender       gender
1  725-750_crif_score   crif_score
2             <25_age          age
3     <575_crif_score   crif_score
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.extract`:

```
df['feature_name'] = df['feature_category'].str.extract('_(.*)')
print(df)

# Output
     feature_category feature_name
0  transgender_gender       gender
1  725-750_crif_score   crif_score
2             <25_age          age
3     <575_crif_score   crif_score
```

`_(.*)` extract all characters after the first underscore.